# Misleading "(more info)" link in Comment Flags view

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, user-interface, moderator-tools

When I'm moderating Comment Flags, there is link that offers more info:

[image: Less info]

When I click on that link, I do indeed get more info:

[image: More info]

But then I see there's yet another link that offers *even more* info.  But when I click on it, I get:

[image: Less info]

So here's my idea: instead of providing "more info", someone who has access to the code can change the word `more` to `less` on when it's expanded and we can all take the rest of the afternoon off.  (Don't tell the management how minor this particular [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) really is!)

Comment: Slow day around here...

Comment: Don't you know that less is more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now.

[image]

I guess someone did take that afternoon off after all.

Comment: Thank you anonymous developer!  (Of course the issue was so trivial I hadn't even noticed the change.  Hmmm...)